# Редактировать input двойным кликом или тапом на мобильном

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо чтобы по двойному клику и тапу на мобилках редактировался Input, но мой код почему то не работает на мобильных устройствах. И ещё после того как заполняется Input всегда можно редактировать, ожидалось, что он примет первоначальное состояние. Идеально было бы заменить readonly на disable

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
    </td>
        <td>
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
    </td>
        <td>
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
      <input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" value="111">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Просто из любопытства - а для чего это?

Comment: @DrMcSheen для того чтобы можно было всё таблицу скопировать например

Comment: @Сергей, тогда проще кнопку рядом сделать ака "Скопировать таблицу". К тому же это будет удобно, если таблица большая.